# Unable to send a email from java program : Unable to relay for abc@wipro.com

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email using a java program using this post [Java Point Post](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api).

```
import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  

public class SendMailBySite {  
 public static void main(String[] args) {  

  String host="IPADDRESS";  
  final String user="abc@wipro.com";//change accordingly  
  final String password="xxx";//change accordingly  

  String to="abc@wipro.com";//change accordingly  

   //Get the session object  
   Properties props = new Properties();  
   props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
      }  
    });  

   //Compose the message  
    try {  
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress

(to));  
     message.setSubject("javatpoint");  
     message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using 

JavaMail API");  

    //send the message  
     Transport.send(message);  

     System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  

     } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
 }  
}
```

I have entered IpAddress correctly and my mail id an password correctly. But when am trying to run this program am getting some exception.

```
java SendEmail
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
        class javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
        class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for abc@wipro.com

        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
        at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:27)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**javax.mail.SendFailedException: 550 Unable to relay for my-address**

> This is not a JavaMail problem. This is an error reply from your SMTP
>   mail server. It indicates that your mail server is not configured to
>   allow you to send mail through it

[Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#norelay)

Try changing the smtp host(For ex google).Also check [send email via google SMTP](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. What can be done?? Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons can be

- The sender has been blocked by the recipient's mail server.This could be due to a spam configuration at the SMTP server.
- The SMTP cannot verify who the sender is and will not allow sending emails.
- Mailbox unavailable for the user mentioned in the From address of the email.